# Improve performance of React Native FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist, react-flatlist

I am building a new mobile app at my company in React Native (I am the only one with React Native experience). I also cannot much share code due to privacy and security reasons but I am not asking for specific code, just suggestions.

In this new app I am using a `<FlatList/>` to render an array of dynamic slides. The core functionality of the app is for users to work through a decision tree. There are many decision trees in our database.

When the user has made a selection to determine the tree they will get, I fetch the first 3 levels of nodes, each time they get to the 2nd to last level, I fetch a new batch of nodes.

I then have some const `slides = useMemo(...)` which then determines which nodes need to be rendered. This slides array is passed into the `data` attribute of my FlatList and then I have a function `renderItem` which returns the relevant component based on the item in the `slides` array.

Of course, with a big tree, this array could grow a lot, and thus the FlatList would be rendering countless components.

I am guessing this could be the reason for the log:

```
 LOG  VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. {"contentLength": 2751, "dt": 38699, "prevDt": 539}
```

I have considered perhaps only rendering the current item, as well as the items prior and after the current item, so that only 3 items are in the FlatList at all times.

I am not sure if this would solve the problem, as the items in the FlatList would still be changing.

I am also not sure how I would handle the indexing, but I am sure I can work that out myself.

But yeah, I guess my main point of concern is how to improve performance with my FlatList, given the data can be quite big and dynamic.

Thanks

Comment: I recommend that you add the code for the FlatList parent component render, as well as the RenderItem method and where you placed it